# Julia: GLM plot logit function

Tags: plot, julia, glm, plots.jl

I am working with a lot of data an just calculated a logistic regression using glm in julia. What I do is to check different effects on the job finding rate, which I have as 0 or 1.
Now I would like to plot my results. I have the gilman/hill book where they do a similar exercise but in R (also with glm).
What they do to plot is:

```
fit.1 <- glm(switch ~ dist, family=binomial(link="logit"))

jitter.binary <- (a, jitt=.05){
  ifelse(a==0, runif(length(a), 0, jitt), runif(length(a), 1-jitt, 1))
  }

switch.jitter <- jitter.binary(X)
plot(dist, switch.jitter)
curve(invlogit (coef(fit.1)[1] + coef(fit.1)[2]*x), add=TRUE)
```

My question is quite basic I think, how can I do something similar in julia as I am not very fond of the R code.
And for plots I use Plots.jl

I hope someone will be able to help me, and if you need more information just let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Plots
plot(x, predict(fit1), seriestype = :line) #where x is your predictor variable
```

Updated to include @pkofod 's comment

Comment: or just
     plot(x, predict(fit1), line=:line)

Comment: To clarify: the default value for the line keyword is :path. Path will just draw a line between the first (x,y) pair, to the second, to the third, to the ..., last pair. If you specify line = :line, it will sort by x first, so you get your "usual" line plot, without having to sort x and the associated y's first.

Comment: Nice one, @pkofod !

Comment: Thank you Michael and pkofod, this really helped me, especially the line=:line part

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't the predict part that really helped you the most? (kidding :-p )